# How to represent a period between two specific datetimes in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is there a Pythonic way to represent, as a single object, the period between two given `datetime`s? **Not** the *amount* of time between them (aka. `timedelta`), but the actual period, between for example `datetime(2000, 1, 1)` (inclusive) and `datetime(2000, 1, 2, hour=6)` (exclusive). The use case is that I need to take a bunch of start and end `datetime`s and join them together, creating a minimal set of non-overlapping periods representing all the inputs. I know how to do that, but I don't know whether there is a *convenient* way of doing it in Python, where I could for example join periods easily, like this:

```
first_start = datetime(2000, 1, 1)
first_end = datetime(2000, 1, 2, hour=6)
first = period(first_start, first_end)
second_start = datetime(2000, 1, 1, hour=3)
second_end = datetime(2000, 1, 2, hour=9)
second = period(second_start, second_end)
expected = period(first_start, second_end)

assert first + second == period(first_start, second_end)
```

Comment: A [`timedelta` object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects)?

Comment: @jdehesa No, clarified.

Answer (score 1):

The [DateTimeRange](https://github.com/thombashi/DateTimeRange) library may give you some help with this. It does not offer that functionality out of the box, but I think it makes it easy to write.

```
from datetimerange import DateTimeRange

def simplify_ranges(dtrs):
    if not dtrs:
        return []
    dtrs = sorted(dtrs, key=lambda dtr: dtr.start_datetime)
    simplified = []
    current = dtrs[0]
    for dtr in dtrs[1:]:
        if current.intersection(dtr).is_valid_timerange():
            current = current.encompass(dtr)
        else:
            simplified.append(current)
            current = dtr
    simplified.append(current)
    return simplified

dtrs = [
    DateTimeRange("2019-01-25T00:00:00+0000", "2019-01-30T00:00:00+0000"),
    DateTimeRange("2019-01-01T00:00:00+0000", "2019-01-10T00:00:00+0000"),
    DateTimeRange("2019-01-21T00:00:00+0000", "2019-01-22T00:00:00+0000"),
    DateTimeRange("2019-01-20T00:00:00+0000", "2019-01-21T00:00:00+0000"),
    DateTimeRange("2019-01-06T00:00:00+0000", "2019-01-15T00:00:00+0000"),
]

print(*simplify_ranges(dtrs), sep='\n')
# 2019-01-01T00:00:00+0000 - 2019-01-15T00:00:00+0000
# 2019-01-20T00:00:00+0000 - 2019-01-22T00:00:00+0000
# 2019-01-25T00:00:00+0000 - 2019-01-30T00:00:00+0000
```